# write a string into a WebView field

Tags: android, html, webview

I have an app thats reading a barcode (Code128) from the camera preview.
I have the barcode result in a string or as a barcode.

I am accessing a web application from a software company and want to past the string into the active html field.

The user should decide in which field he wants to have the barcode value pasted.
How do i get the "active"(clicked on field) in the Webview and how do I paste the string automatically into it?

I would to write the string into the field like the soft keyboard does.

Best regards,
Arne

Comment: can u tried for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use JavaScript Interface in Android WebView To Detect Click On Fields And Pass Parameter's To Them .

Answer (score 0):

use JavaScript in webView in android

in html file 2 elements (username and button)

```
<html>

//...


<input name="username" type="text" id="id_username">

<input type="submit" class="button-green" value="Log in">

//...

</html>
```

create Custom WebViewClient for webView

```
class WebViewClientCustom extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.i("WebViewClientCustom", "Redirecting URL " + url);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        Log.i("WebViewClientCustom", "Page error: " + description);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        try {
            view.addJavascriptInterface(new UserData(), "UserData");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("WebViewClientCustom", "Loading URL: " + url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(webView, url);

        Log.i("WebViewClientCustom", "onPageFinished");
        //add javascript
        webView.loadUrl("javascript: document.getElementsByClassName(\"button-green\")[0].onclick = function() {\n        var username = document.getElementById(\"id_username\").value;\n          UserData.saveUsername(username);\n    };");

    }

}
```

create class UserData

```
public class UserData {

    public static String username;

    //saveData
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void saveUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

and end

```
WebView mWebView = new WebView(activity);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientCustom()); //add custom WebViewClient
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //enable JavaScript for webView
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the javascript suggestion!

I figured out a pretty simple solution with the android Webview and Javascript.
I just need it write this one string into my active field so I dont need an Javascript adapter.

This worked for me:

```
public void setValue()
{

    String jscript =  "document.activeElement.value="+"'"+ yourVariable+"'";
    mWebView.evaluateJavascript(jscript,null);

}
```

This string gets the active field an writes "yourvariable" into it.